# How to partition a Pandas Series based on value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like the following:

```
>>> df
        order_received
0            1
1            1
2            0
3            0
4            1
5            0
6            0
```

I'd like to split this into `(1), (1), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0)` i.e. split the Series every time there is a `1`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with `cumsum` with reverse order of your columns, then `groupby` + `list`

```
df.groupby(df.order_received.iloc[::-1].eq(1).cumsum())['order_received'].apply(list).iloc[::-1]
Out[419]: 
order_received
3          [1]
2          [1]
1    [0, 0, 1]
0       [0, 0]
Name: order_received, dtype: object
```

Method two using `shift` follow by `cumsum`

```
df.groupby(df.order_received.shift().fillna(0).cumsum())['order_received'].apply(list)
Out[432]: 
order_received
0.0          [1]
1.0          [1]
2.0    [0, 0, 1]
3.0       [0, 0]
Name: order_received, dtype: object
```

Comment: This can make do without `.eq()` :)

Comment: @LittleChild Yes you are right :-) , Just in case you have some checker rather than 1